# Calculate average time differences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with different IDs and for each ID there are two different times (Time1 and Time2). I need to check if Time1 is bigger than Time2 then I need to subtract X= Time1 -Time2. If Time2 is bigger I need to subtract Y=Time2 - Time1.

This is my result of the query:

```
ID      Time1                   Time2              Result
1   2018-02-12 08:00:00   2018-02-12 09:28:00     -00:32
2   2018-02-12 07:00:00   2018-02-12 08:04:00     -00:56
3   2018-02-12 06:00:00   2018-02-12 08:10:00      00:10
4   2018-02-12 06:00:00   2018-02-12 08:34:00      00:34
```

If Time1 is bigger I add a '-' in the output to differentiate.
What I want now is to calculate the average of the result times but separately for the positive ones and negatives one. What I want is something like this:

```
(00:32 + 00:56) /2
```

and

```
(00:10 + 00:34) /2
```

Time1 and Time2 are stored as Datetimes but I convert them to strings because I just want to see the time difference I don't need dates.
Is there a way to calculate the average?

Comment: Use case expressions to average the positive and negative values separately.

Comment: Your maths looks incorrect. How is the difference between the Time1 and Time2 equal what you have for the Result column?

Comment: How did u acheived-`_` values  in result output ?

Comment: I don't actually understand how you get your values for the column `Result`. In your sample data, `Time2` is greater than `Time1` in every instance. Also, if you area always subtracted the **larger** value from the smaller, you will always end up with a positive number. Are we missing something here..?

Comment: Also, it's worth noting "negative time" does not exist in SQL Server. You cannot have a value such as `'-00:32'` stored as `time`. Thus, you'd be forced to store, or treat the value as a `(n)varchar`, which you won't be able to use `AVG` on. Or, you'll need to do some string manipulations and conversions. Either way, the full picture is unclear here.

Comment: Wrong data aside, the solution is trivial. Group by whether Time1 is greater than Time2, and Sum Time1 - Time2 (or the  other way round).

Answer (score 0):

use avg() to find the average. 
To find the average of negatives -

`SELECT AVG(Result) FROM table_name WHERE Result like '-%';`

Answer (score 0):

separate:

```
select time1, time2, result ,
case when result like '-%' then avg(result)
case when result like '+%' then avg(result)
else result
end new_result
from table
```

If you DO not want to segregate positive and negative:

```
select avg(total) from
( select sum(ABS(result_col) as total from table) x
```

Comment: `ABS(result)` isn't going to work; you can't have a negative time, so there's no such thing as an "absolute" value for it. As I mention in the comments, the "only" way to store a time as a negative, would be as a `(n)varchar`, which you then can't perform aggregate funcitons on.

Comment: It is mentioned in the question that he is going to convert datetime into string to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had to exclude the logic for getting the column `Result` here, as your logic doesn't make sense (as described in my comment). To get the average, however, you have to do a lot of conversion. Negative Time doesn't exist (in SQL Server), so you have to do string manipulations and conversions to get the values you want.

If you need to work out `Result` in this query too, then you need to explain it better. `'09:28'` - `'08:00'` is not "`'-00:32'`" (and certainly not a negative, as the first value is great). It makes no sense.

Anyway, **assuming** you do have the value/logic for `Result` already:

```
CREATE TABLE #Time (ID int,
                    Time1 datetime2(0),
                    Time2 datetime2(0),
                    Result varchar(6))
INSERT INTO #Time
VALUES (1,'20180212 08:00:00','20180212 09:28:00', '-00:32'),
       (2,'20180212 07:00:00','20180212 08:04:00', '-00:56'),
       (3,'20180212 06:00:00','20180212 08:10:00', '00:10'),
       (4,'20180212 06:00:00','20180212 08:34:00', '00:34');
GO

WITH Conversion AS (
    SELECT CASE LEFT(Result,1) WHEN '-' THEN CONVERT(time, STUFF(Result,1,1,''))
                               ELSE CONVERT(time, Result)
           END AS AbsoluteResult,
           CASE LEFT(Result,1) WHEN '-' THEN '-' ELSE '' END AS PosNeg
    FROM #Time T)
SELECT PosNeg + LEFT(CONVERT(time,DATEADD(SECOND, AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, AbsoluteResult)), 0)),5) AS AverageTime
FROM Conversion
GROUP BY PosNeg;

GO
DROP TABLE #Time;
```